# How to list dependencies shown from the output of apt install across multiple lines?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I am trying to use apt to install a new package and the confirmation screen shows all dependencies in a single line.

**Example Output:** [screenshot showing output of `apt install postgresql`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgW5a.png)

***Please ignore the `-y` flag in the screenshot. I don't usually use the -y flag but didn't have any other screenshot to share hence used the one with the `-y` flag present.***

> ```
> (base) uk@uk-Latitude-7280:~$ sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> The following additional packages will be installed:
>  libcommon-sense-perl libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl libpq5 libtypes-serialiser-perl >pgdg-keyring postgresql-14 postgresql-client-14 postgresql-client-common >postgresql->common sysstat
> Suggested packages:
>  postgresql-doc postgresql-doc-14 isag
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>  libcommon-sense-perl libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl libtypes-serialiser-perl >pgdg->keyring postgresql postgresql-14 postgresql-client-14 postgresql-client-common >postgresql-common
>  sysstat
> The following packages will be upgraded:
>  libpq5
> ```

**Expected output:**

> ```
> (base) uk@uk-Latitude-7280:~$ sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> The following additional packages will be installed:
>  libcommon-sense-perl 
>  libjson-perl 
>  libjson-xs-perl 
>  libpq5 
>  libtypes-serialiser-perl
>  pgdg-keyring
>  postgresql-14
>  postgresql-client-14
>  postgresql-client-common
>  postgresql-common
>  sysstat
> Suggested packages:
>  postgresql-doc
>  postgresql-doc-14
>  isag
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>  libcommon-sense-perl
>  libjson-perl
>  libjson-xs-perl
>  libtypes-serialiser-perl
>  pgdg-keyring
>  postgresql
>  postgresql-14
>  postgresql-client-14
>  postgresql-client-common
>  postgresql-common
>  sysstat
> The following packages will be upgraded:
>  libpq5
> ```

**Edit: Added clarity around the `-y` flag used within the screenshot.**

Comment: What does it matter; you've used `-y` which means you're not reading that output & have given permission for it to be operated on regards of any provided output.  Your use case makes no sense   (*multiple lines also creates problems for those that read the output of installed packages as it can exceed the lines of display rather easily; but in your case you're not even reading that output*)

Comment: You could try the interactive mode of `aptitude`. It will show the planned actions one per line before starting the installation/removal process.

Comment: @guiverc Well in this particular instance I used the `-y` flag because I knew the list of dependencies that would be installed but I seldom use that flag. Just that I didn't have any other screenshot to upload to show as a reference to what I am after hence I had to use the one that I had while installing this particular package. 

I understand the repercussions of multiple lines but still for smaller set of dependencies, multiple lines makes them easier to read.

Comment: Hmmm. In 16 years of using Debian and Ubuntu, I've not seen such an option to format apt output (there are a couple options, but not multi-line). So if it's there at all, it's well hidden.